# Solving second order non-linear DE with boundary condition

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions

I was trying to get some result from this equation but I can't find the solution. please see what is wrong with it??!! thanks

f, s are positive and k will be negative or positive.

```
    Clear["Global`*"] 
    eqn = {(y''[x]/y[x]) + s (y'[x]/y[x])^2 - s (k/y[x]^2) - f/2 == 0};
    k = 3; f = 7/10; s = 1/2;
    sol = DSolve[{eqn, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}, y, x]
```

Comment: nothing wrong with it. Mathematica can't solve it. Here is Maple's solution $y \left(x \right) = \mathit{RootOf}\left(-\left(\int_{\textit{\_b}}^{\textit{\_Z}}\frac{\textit{\_a} \sqrt{30}}{\sqrt{\textit{\_a} \left(7 \textit{\_a}^{3}+30 \mathit{RootOf}\left(-\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{97+30 \textit{\_Z}}\right)+90 \textit{\_a} \right)}}d \textit{\_a} \right)+x +\int_{\textit{\_b}}^{1}\frac{\textit{\_a} \sqrt{30}}{\sqrt{\textit{\_a} \left(7 \textit{\_a}^{3}+30 \mathit{RootOf}\left(-\sqrt{30}+\sqrt{97+30 \textit{\_Z}}\right)+90 \textit{\_a} \right)}}d \textit{\_a} \right)$

Comment: @Nasser:  I'm not familiar with Maple syntax, but does that answer include the boundary conditions?  I ask because Mathematica does return an answer if the boundary conditions are removed from the `DSolve`  (It returns an ugly object in terms of `Solve` and `Root` and `EllipticF`, but I suspect it's effectively the same as Maple's solution in the general case.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  Yes, the above answer includes the BC. Here is screen shot. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F98ce.png)

Comment: Because the Maple solution is of little value unless evaluated numerically, `eqn` may as well be solved numerically with `NDSolveValue[{eqn, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}, y[x], {x, -6, 5}]`.  I did make some progress with the symbolic solution but ultimately had to invert it numerically.